# SNS Filter policy hitting limit error after quota increase

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, subscription

I have this scenario where my SNS subscription has one filter policy with 150 values in it. I know there is cap on the value, so I have requested AWS for quota increase but even after the increased policy limit, I get this error

```html
Couldn't set the filter policy for the subscription.
Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: An error occurred while setting attribute subscription filter policy. Invalid parameter: FilterPolicy: Filter policy is too complex
```

```
{
"test":[ 
"A",
"B",
....
....
<150 values in total>
]
}
```

Could someone point, what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Quick questions: Are you sure your request for quota increase is fulfilled?
Can you post your filter policy?

Comment: Yes, My quota limit has been increased but still the same issue

Comment: Then probably problem lies with your filter policy, can you past the filter policy

Comment: I have added the sample template

Answer (score 1):

It is not fully propagated yet it takes some time for the updated limit to be fully propagated throughout the system. Secondly, the total size of your filter policy is too large. There is a limit to the total size of the policy.

Comment: I tried after 24 hrs but still the same response. I see the maximum policy size is 256KB, my json array is less than that
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscription-filter-policy-constraints.html